# How to add wifi drivers in custom kernel?

Tags: kernel

I compiled the Ubuntu Mate 16.04 kernel with custom RT patches on raspberry pi 3.

The kernel is 4.1.19-rt22-v7. Everything is working accept for the wifi drivers. They are missing from /lib/firmware.

Do I just copy the wifi modules to /lib/firmware  and reboot?

Comment: *"Do I just copy the wifi modules to /lib/firmware and reboot?"* -> Should more often work than not, and in the case of the Pi 3's built-in wifi, yes, but:  To split hairs, firmware is distinct from the actual driver, about which the kernel is pretty picky, and the presence of the firmware doesn't mean you have the driver (`brcmfmac.ko`) built.

Comment: @goldilocks I loaded brcmfmac.ko and placed the firmware and wifi is not working. Is something wrong with the modules?

Comment: What does `ip link` show?

Comment: Run `dmesg` right after `modprobe brcmfmac`. You should get a line saying which firmware was used or (if none could be used) what went wrong.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I am dumb. I placed the firmware in the wrong place. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following on 15.10, but AFAIK they should already be in 16.04

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
sudo wget https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree/raw/master/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.txt
```

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/solved-update-mate-15-10-for-the-raspberry-pi3-wont-boot/4508

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you correct the wget statement? It points at the wrong URL.